# Woocommerce account page shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Does Woocommerce have shortcodes for each account page so that you have the pages separate from the menu?

`Hiding the navigation is unfortunately not an option`

Answer (score 0):

[woocommerce_my_account] -> account page

---

[woocommerce_order_tracking] -> Lets a user see the status of an order by entering their order details.

---

these two shortcodes for account page
another pages doesn't have shortcodes but have filter to change or add somthings to page.